# How to get the average from computed columns in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, average, aggregate-functions

I have a query:

```
SELECT sum(column_1),
   sum(...) as sum_1,
   sum(...) as sum_2,
   sum(...) as sum_3
FROM table_1
```

How to get an average data from sum_1, sum_2, sum_3?
If I write a query in the next way:

```
SELECT sum(column_1),
   sum(...) as sum_1,
   sum(...) as sum_2,
   sum(...) as sum_3,
   avg(sum_1, sum_2, sum_3)
FROM table_1
```

I got an Error:

> [42703] ERROR: column "sum_1" does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want to compute the average of the three columns on the same row. If so, you don't need `avg()` (that is an aggregate function, that operates across rows). Instead, you can use regular artihmetics:

```
SELECT *, (sum_1 + sum_2 + sum_3) / 3 as sum_average
FROM (
    SELECT sum(column_1), sum(...) as sum_1, sum(...) as sum_2,sum(...) as sum_3
    FROM table_1
) t
```

The subquery is not striclty necessary. You could also repeat the `sum()`s, like:

```
SELECT sum(column_1), sum(...) as sum_1, sum(...) as sum_2,sum(...) as sum_3,
    (sum(...) + sum(...) + sum(...)) / 3 as sum_average
FROM table_1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Which query will be faster?